# Load external page with Swig in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, include, swig-template

I am trying to include the HTML generated in an external page in a NodeJS module, using Swig to generate the view. What I want to do is basically the same behaviour you get with the `<c:import/>` tag in JSTL.

I have tried this so far:

- `{{ include http://another.webpage }}`
- `{{ include 'http://another.webpage' }}`
- `{% include http://another.webpage %}`
- `{% include 'http://another.webpage' %}`

But none of them worked.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that since the code of the tag `include` look at a file related to his current path. With the current version of Swig code, you can't do it.

You can find the code of this tag [here](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/master/lib/tags/include.js).

But you could create your custom tag in Swig that load an HTTP resource.

Comment: Not sure why anyone down-voted this. This is the correct answer.